# How do I disable tab swiping on Map element - Android?

Tags: c#, .net, google-maps, maui

I have a shell content with tabs. The issue I am having is that when I swipe left on the map in order to translate the map to the side, the tab is swiping instead, and going to the left (or right) tab. This is my `AppShell.xaml`

```
<Shell
    x:Class="CellularSignal1.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CellularSignal1"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">

    <TabBar x:Name="MyTabBar">
        <Tab x:Name="CellularInfo" Title="Cellular Info">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate=...
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Mapper}" Route="Mapper"/>
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>
</Shell>
```

Where mapper has a google map element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CellularSignal1"
             xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps"
             x:Class="CellularSignal1.Mapper"
             x:DataType="local:Mapper"
             Title="Mapper"
             x:Name="myMap">
            <StackLayout x:Name="stack">
                <maps:Map x:Name="mapView" WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="300" />
            </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

What is the easiest way to have the swipe action only apply to the map element, and not to the outer tab swiping when swiping on the map?

Comment: Did you try the solution in my answer? And is there any question I can help you?

Answer (score 0):

There is an existed issue about [Can't disable swipe on Shell Top Tabs](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10182). You can follow up it on the github.

And you can make the tab bar show at the bottom of the screen. Such as:

```
<Shell
    x:Class="CellularSignal1.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CellularSignal1"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">

    <TabBar x:Name="MyTabBar">
            <ShellContent Titile="Page1" ContentTemplate=...
            <ShellContent Titile="Page2" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Mapper}" Route="Mapper"/>
    </TabBar>
</Shell>
```

In this condition, the swiping will only work for the Map control.